# Elasticsearch search query quide

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

Currently I'm working on **ELK 8** (Filebeat, Logstash, Elasticsearch & Kibana) stuck in middle

Sample log is here,

```
2021-07-30 16:34:22 INFO  com.example.OrderRest [fhxh750df392] Session opened OId 31324
2021-07-30 16:34:22 INFO  com.example.OrderRest [fhxh750df392] Transaction started TId T312487
........
2021-07-30 16:34:22 INFO  com.example.OrderRest [tegq842sh980] Session opened OId 31325
2021-07-30 16:34:22 INFO  com.example.OrderRest [tegq842sh980] Transaction started TId T312488
........
2021-07-30 16:34:22 INFO  com.example.OrderRest [fhxh750df392] Session closed
2021-07-30 16:34:22 INFO  com.example.OrderRest [tegq842sh980] Session closed
```

**Issue:** If I query with **OId** **31324**, getting only matching document as below

```
GET _search
{
  "query":{
    "match": {"OId": "31324"}
  }
}
```

result:

```
2021-07-30 16:34:22 INFO  com.example.OrderRest [fhxh750df392] Session opened OId 31324
```

Instead, the result should also include transaction generated all next matching records with request id **fhxh750df392** like

```
2021-07-30 16:34:22 INFO  com.example.OrderRest [fhxh750df392] Session opened OId 31324
2021-07-30 16:34:22 INFO  com.example.OrderRest [fhxh750df392] Transaction started TId T312487
........
2021-07-30 16:34:22 INFO  com.example.OrderRest [fhxh750df392] Session closed
```

Like, if I query with **TId** **T312487**, result should be

```
2021-07-30 16:34:22 INFO  com.example.OrderRest [fhxh750df392] Transaction started TId T312487
........
2021-07-30 16:34:22 INFO  com.example.OrderRest [fhxh750df392] Session closed
```

I'm new to ELK can anyone guide me how to do

Comment: are you trying to writing an elastic dsl query or can you use any others like logstash config as well. i would suggest to apply grok pattern in logstash config code to achieve this

Comment: You have not given full details like how you are processing and indexing log to elasticsearch and  etc.. Elasticsearch will not provide response which you are expecting as it is indexing each line as seperat document in Elasticsearch. You need to use grok pattern to capture set of logs line from Session started to session closed.

Comment: @SagarPatel, I'm also trying the same but how to achieve through grok.

Comment: @nay grok pattern seems also not possible because there might be multipul session logging at same time. You can add unique id for each session in log and when you logging and while query to elastisearch, you can apply collpase on unique id.

Comment: @SagarPatel, currently my application log is also generated in the same way, per each request id will be generated & same is logging but how to group all these at once. whether grouping multiple statements into one document is a good idea or not

Comment: You can grouped multipul line while indexing but what i am asking is that you can add unique id for each session so if you are generating 3 logs line for one session then it should have single unique id then you can index single log line as single document and query time you can collapse based on unique id. Currently id is available at `Open seassion` logs line only and it is not available at `Close session` line.

Comment: @SagarPatel I don't know what id generated during grouping & indexing I know only search keyword how can I collapse both at query time

Comment: @nay please check below my answer, it will give you the clear understanding of what i am suggesting you. You will not get result in single query and you need to use two query to get result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below grok pattern for converting your logs to structure:

```
%{DATESTAMP:date}%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:level}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:class}%{SPACE}\[%{GREEDYDATA:pid}\]%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

The above grok pattern will convert each log line in below format:

```json
{
  "date": "21-07-30 16:34:22",
  "level": "INFO",
  "pid": "fhxh750df392",
  "message": "Session opened OId 31324",
  "class": "com.example.OrderRest "
}
```

I have considered value in brackets as process id e.g. `[fhxh750df392]`.

Once you have above logs in the index, you can use 2 separate queries for getting data:

**Frist Query** for getting pid where the query is matched:

```json
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "message": "31324"
    }
  }, 
  "aggs": {
    "pid": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "pid.keyword",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result of first query:

```json
 "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "pid" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "fhxh750df392",
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

**Second Query** for getting actual result, Here you need to use pid from above response and pass to below query.

```json
{
  "size": 20,
  "_source": false, 
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "pid": [
        "fhxh750df392"
      ]
    }
  },
  "collapse": {
    "field": "pid.keyword",
    "inner_hits": {
      "name": "logs"
    }
  }
}
```

Response of the second query, similar to what you are looking:

```json
"hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 3,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "logtest",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "BMXTFIEB3bStuRaWDAtm",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "fields" : {
          "pid.keyword" : [
            "fhxh750df392"
          ]
        },
        "inner_hits" : {
          "logs" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 3,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : 1.0,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "logtest",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "BMXTFIEB3bStuRaWDAtm",
                  "_score" : 1.0,
                  "_source" : {
                    "date" : "21-07-30 16:34:22",
                    "level" : "INFO",
                    "pid" : "fhxh750df392",
                    "message" : "Session opened OId 31324",
                    "class" : "com.example.OrderRest "
                  }
                },
                {
                  "_index" : "logtest",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "BcXTFIEB3bStuRaWkAuX",
                  "_score" : 1.0,
                  "_source" : {
                    "date" : "21-07-30 16:34:22",
                    "level" : "INFO",
                    "pid" : "fhxh750df392",
                    "message" : "Transaction started TId T312487",
                    "class" : "com.example.OrderRest "
                  }
                },
                {
                  "_index" : "logtest",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "BsXTFIEB3bStuRaWwAua",
                  "_score" : 1.0,
                  "_source" : {
                    "date" : "21-07-30 16:34:22",
                    "level" : "INFO",
                    "pid" : "fhxh750df392",
                    "message" : "Session closed",
                    "class" : "com.example.OrderRest "
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: yes, u r right but I want to fetch in a single query. is any way to pass the first query response directly as input (all fetched ids in the first query) to the second query. I'm using kibana visualisation

Comment: as far as i know there is no way.

Comment: tq for spending ur valuable time I'm trying from 3 days onwards basically they want it in a single click